# Problem with JQuery - trigger('change') to particular html table row/cell, works on row 0 only

Tags: jquery

I have an html table and the second cell has its html Id set to "Item" on all rows.

If I execute this line with row = 0:

```
$('#Item').eq(row).trigger('change');
```

It does send a change trigger to row 0, and does what I want and
fires onchange.

If row is anything but 0, the trigger is not sent to seemingly any cell as onchange doesn't fire).

I am stuck!!

Can anyone show me the error of my ways?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The `id` attribute is ***unique***!  You can only have ***one*** item with `id="Item"` within the _entire_ page.  Therefore `$('#Item')` will only ever return _one_ item.  Try using a `class` called `Item` instead, then you can use `$('.Item')`.

Comment: Don't add "Solved:" to your title. Add an answer below if you think your solution can help others, otherwise consider deleting this question.

Comment: You'd probably benefit from the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Rocket, I took your advice and retooled it. This works, finally. I had tried .typeahead last night but could not even get that to work BUT: this does. $('.typeahead:eq('+ row +')').trigger('change'); So Thank you again for all your help. Now I can have a "nice" weekend